# Clicking on JTable Cell should display Form into a Container

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpanel

I am new to Java Swing and I am trying to create an application.

I have  a  MainApplication.java file which extends SingleFrameApplication and where I am creating a JPanel named MainPanel. This MainPanel has an AnimatingSplitPane with VERTICAL_SPLIT named SplitPane.

On the Top of the SplitPane, I am adding another JPanel named MainContainer. On the bottom of the SplitPane, I am adding a JPanel named FormContainer. The MainContainer loads the another class named DataSheetTable (a JPanel having JTable).

Now, when user clicks on the cells of the DataSheetTable, I want to load the form into the FormContainer. I don't know, how can I achieve this.

For instance, DatasheetTable has Column1, Column2 and Column3. When user clicks on any cell of Column1, I need to show Form1 into the FormContanier. If it clicks on Column2 cell then I need to show Form2 into FormContanier.

Please let me know with some sample code, how can I achieve loading the forms on the fly to FormContainer.

![Thank you in advance.]

**[Image description for the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BokmS.png)**

Here is sample code for App.java

```
public class App extends SingleFrameApplication {
 @Override protected void startup() {
    configureDefaults();

     View view = getMainView();
     view.setComponent(createMainPanel());

    show(view);
 }

protected JComponent createMainPanel() {
    // Create main panel with demo selection on left and demo/source on right
    mainPanel = new JPanel();
    mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());


    // Create splitpane on right to hold demo and source code
    splitPane = new AnimatingSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);
    mainPanel.add(splitPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    // Create panel to contain main panel
    mainContainer = new JPanel();
    splitPane.setTopComponent(mainContainer);

    DataSheetTable dataSheetTable = new DataSheetTable();
    mainContainer.add(dataSheetTable, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    dataSheetTable.start();

    formContainer = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    splitPane.setBottomComponent(formContainer);
    formContainer.add(new OrganizationForm());

    return mainPanel;
  }
}
```

Here is sample code for DataSheetTable.java file

```
public class DataSheetTable extends JPanel {

    ........
     controlPanel = createControlPanel();
     add(controlPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);


    routingTable = new JTable(routingModel);

   .........

}
```

Comment: Instead explaining your code it'll be better to just show it in your question (like: "A picture is worth a thousand words")

Comment: thank you for your long post, what't your question ????, sample code ---> this forum is full of the great code samples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is your code for intercepting events of table cell clicks:

```
public class App extends JFrame {
    private DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][] {
            { "Value1", "Value2", "Value3" }, { "Object1", "Object2", "Object3" } }, new String[] {
            "Column1", "Column2", "Column3" });
    private JTable table = new JTable(model);
    private JPanel bottomPanel;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                App a = new App();
                a.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                a.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                a.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public App() {
        JSplitPane pane = new JSplitPane();
        pane.setOrientation(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL);
        pane.setLeftComponent(new JScrollPane(table));
        bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel.add(new JLabel("properties for column will be here"));
        pane.setRightComponent(bottomPanel);
        add(pane);

        ListSelectionListener listener = new ListSelectionListener() {
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                int column = table.getSelectedColumn();
                int row = table.getSelectedRow();
                if(row != -1 && column != -1) {
                    bottomPanel.removeAll();
                    //Here you add your components/create appropriate panel
                    //e.g. bottomPanel.add(new PropertiesPanelForValue1(...));
                    bottomPanel.add(new JLabel("User selected column " + column + " and row " + row
                            + " with value: '" + table.getValueAt(row, column) + "'"));
                    bottomPanel.revalidate();
                }
            }
        };
        table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(listener);
        table.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(listener);

        pack();

        pane.setDividerLocation(0.3);
        setSize();
    }

    private void setSize() {
        double widthPart = 0.3;
        double heightPart = 0.5;
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int width = (int) (screenSize.getWidth() * widthPart);
        int height = (int) (screenSize.getHeight() * heightPart);
        setSize(width, height);
        Dimension windowSize = getSize();
        int x = (int) ((screenSize.getWidth() - windowSize.getWidth()) / 2);
        int y = (int) ((screenSize.getHeight() - windowSize.getHeight()) / 2);
        setLocation(x, y);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Looking at your update: Just add to `DataSheetTable` constructor reference to your `FormContainer`:

```
formContainer = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
splitPane.setBottomComponent(formContainer);
formContainer.add(new OrganizationForm());

DataSheetTable dataSheetTable = new DataSheetTable(formContainer);
mainContainer.add(dataSheetTable, BorderLayout.CENTER);
dataSheetTable.start();
```

and in `DataSheetTable` add listener:

```
public class DataSheetTable extends JPanel {

public DataSheetTable(final FormContainer formContainer) {
........
 controlPanel = createControlPanel();
 add(controlPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);


routingTable = new JTable(routingModel);
ListSelectionListener listener = new ListSelectionListener() {...};
routingTable.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(listener);
              routingTable.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(listener);

.........
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. I am sorry, if my question was not clear but JTable is in a different Java Class which extends a JPanel. When user clicks on the cells then it should load form into FormContainer in the different class having JSplitPanel.

Comment: If I correctly understand your comment - this doesn't matter what Swing component ("different Java Class") constains what. You only need a **reference** to a `JTable` and to your `FormContainer` (in my example: `table` and `bottomPanel` instance fields). Add listener to `JTable` and in it: invoke `referenceToFormPanel.removeAll();...` and so on.

Comment: I made edits to the question for better understanding. If you can please give me some sample code how to load form into FormContainer when DataSheetTable's JTable's cells are clicked. I would appreciate.